# Typeguard doesn't work inside await new Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typeguards

I have a typeguard that check is authResponse exists. It works well, but inside await new Promise i have a compiler error, that object is possible null. I check type into deeplink condition and there is AuthResponse, but inside new Promise type is AuthResponse | null. Could you tell me, please, is it possible to make this type work correctly inside new Promise without optional chaining?

```
const hasAuthResponse = (
  response: AuthResponse | null,
): response is AuthResponse => !!response;

if (hasAuthResponse(authResponse)) {
  const deepLink = getRedirectDeepLink(
    redirect_to_scheme,
    "",
    allowedSchemas ?? undefined,
  );

  if (deepLink) {
    router.push({
      pathname: deepLink,
      query: {
        rsid: authResponse.rsid,
      },
    });

    return;
  }

  await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    helper
      ? helper.propagateSession(
          authResponse.rsid,
          {
            back: back ?? Urls.PROFILE,
          },
          resolve,
        )
      : resolve();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't quite complete, but I'd wager `authResponse` is probably not `const`.

Since the promise call is asynchronous, TypeScript infers that the value of `authResponse` could have become `null` by the time `propagateSession` gets called.

The easy fix is to rebind `authResponse` into a local name and use that (since it's guaranteed that its type will remain `AuthResponse`):

```
if (hasAuthResponse(authResponse)) {
    const authResponse2 = authResponse;  // inferred type: AuthResponse
```

but since you only really use the `rsid` field from the AuthResponse, you can just destructure it out of the `authResponse` and use it in the subsequent calls:

```
if (hasAuthResponse(authResponse)) {
    const {rsid} = authResponse;
```

Comment: Thank you, the example with destructure work for me